# Trigger for creating a new record after new user creation doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a `settings` table and a `users` table. I want to create a trigger to insert a new `settings` record every time a new user gets created and reference the id of the newly created user in the `settings` record(`settings.user_id` in this case). Currently, I've come up with this trigger and function but whenever I try to `insert` a record into the `users` table the query fails to execute.

Procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_settings() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO settings (user_id) VALUES (OLD.id);
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$
```

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER create_settings 
AFTER INSERT ON users 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_settings();
```

and here's the error I get:

```sql
ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" of relation "settings" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (95a8d1ae-cf9d-40be-b5d2-b2d231fb7e1b, null, null, null, null, light, 2022-01-02 15:29:14.290823).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO settings (user_id) VALUES (OLD.id)"
PL/pgSQL function create_settings() line 3 at SQL statement
```

The only field that I need is the first `null` from the error which is the actual reference to the user by ID(most of the values that are null are optional and are `NULL` by default).

Comment: What is ```OLD``` when we are dealing with an insert? Better try ```NEW```

Comment: @Islingre unfortunately that didn't work. I'm getting the same error, just instead of `OLD` it's `NEW` 

Comment: Then `NEW.id` is `NULL`.  What is the `INSERT`  query for the table `users`? What is the table definition for `users`? Add answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html). In particular the difference between **row** level and **statement** level triggers. You save a statement level trigger. Statement level triggers do not have the pseudo roes Old or New values, They are all null. You need a row level trigger to get values from Old or New. So:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_settings 
AFTER INSERT ON users 
for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_settings();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to notice that the OLD variable is only available for triggers that execute UPDATE/DELETE in row-level [as shown here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), so in this case is not possible to get the data you want with an INSERT trigger.